# WSL2 does not start after spacedesk installation

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, wsl2

It seems to be an issue with spacedesk that after installation WSL2 does not start anymore throwing an error "Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS. For information please visit [https://aka.ms/wsl2-install"](https://aka.ms/wsl2-install%22).

There's a discussion on the spacedesk forum about the problem but no solution.
https://www.spacedesk.net/forums/topic/wsl2-not-starting-after-spacedesk-installation/

- Before installation WSL2 was working fine.
- UEFI has virtualization enabled.
- Virtual Machine Platform & Windows Subsystem for Linux is enabled in Windows features.
- Trying turn off those features and on does not do anything.
- Uninstalling spacedesk does not resolve the issue.

Can anyone help out to find the solution?

CoreInfo64 dump

```
AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
Microcode signature: 00000000
HTT             *       Multicore
CET             -       Supports Control Flow Enforcement Technology
Kernel CET      -       Kernel-mode CET Enabled
User CET        -       User-mode CET Allowed
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             *       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          *       Supports AMD SKINIT
SGX             -       Supports Intel SGX

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            -       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            -       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              -       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    -       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          *       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           *       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
AVX2            -       Supports AVX2 instruction extensions
AVX-512-F       -       Supports AVX-512 Foundation instructions
AVX-512-DQ      -       Supports AVX-512 double and quadword instructions
AVX-512-IFAMA   -       Supports AVX-512 integer Fused multiply-add instructions
AVX-512-PF      -       Supports AVX-512 prefetch instructions
AVX-512-ER      -       Supports AVX-512 exponential and reciprocal instructions
AVX-512-CD      -       Supports AVX-512 conflict detection instructions
AVX-512-BW      -       Supports AVX-512 byte and word instructions
AVX-512-VL      -       Supports AVX-512 vector length instructions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          -       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          -       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            -       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             -       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           *       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         *       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           -       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           -       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             -       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             -       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          -       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              -       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            -       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         -       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            -       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            -       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            -       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            -       Implements MSR for power management
TM              -       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             -       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             -       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 0000000D (Basic), 8000001E (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 48 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 00600F20

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**----  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**--  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
********  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
********  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
*-------  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
**------  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
**------  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
********  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    8 MB, Assoc  64, LineSize  64
-*------  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--*-----  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
--**----  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
--**----  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
---*----  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----*---  Data Cache          4, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
----**--  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
----**--  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
-----*--  Data Cache          5, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------*-  Data Cache          6, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
------**  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   64 KB, Assoc   2, LineSize  64
------**  Unified Cache       4, Level 2,    2 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
-------*  Data Cache          7, Level 1,   16 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
********  Group 0
```

Comment: Uninstall all required features then reinstall all required feature rebooting after each step.  Disable and then enable hardware virtualization (VT-x or AMD-V) depending on your hardware rebooting your machine between each step. What other software do you have installed that might be using the hardware virtualization capabilities?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your comment. I already tried several times to disable and enable Window features, turn off and on the Virtualization in the UEFI. I do have VirtualBox which by the way also stopped working throwing error: WHvCapabilityCodeHypervisorPresent is FALSE! Make sure you have enabled the 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' feature. (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM). I have another computer where WSL and Vagrant both working fine together.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running.  What version of VirtualBox are you running.  Only the current version of both Windows 10 and VirtualBox support a configuration where Hyper-V is also enabled.  Have you tried my suggestion, exactly, the way I suggested?  It's worth a try to uninstall ANY and ALL software that might be using the hardware virtualization x86 extension, then and only then, install the optional features for WSL2. Is `hypervisorlaunchtype` set to `auto` or `off`?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Pro 21H2, VirtualBox 6.1.18 r142142. `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to `auto`. I followed your suggestions: 1. Turn off Windows features, reboot; 2. Turn off Virtualization in UEFI, reboot; 3. Turn on Virtualization in UEFI, reboot; 4. Turn on Virtual Machine Platform, reboot; 5. Turn on Windows Subsystem for Linux, reboot;

Unfortunately, nothing helped.

Comment: Please verify that Core Isolation and You should also verify that Virtualization-based Security (VBS) are disabled.

Comment: Just to confirm. If you run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and run `bcdedit /v` it shows that `hypervisorlaunchtype` is `off` instead of `auto` correct?

Comment: @Ramhound correct, it stays `off`. Is there are a way to check, what software is taking over virtualization? Maybe there are some leftovers after spacedesk that prevent to let other software work. Some people on other pages claimed that the only option was to reinstall Windows with Keep personal files option, however my system is a bit complicated in terms of software and reinstalling everything at this point is not an option for me.

Comment: @Ramhound Core Isolation was disabled as well as VBS.

Comment: Until CoreInfo64 indicates that hardware virtualization is available, you likely have something installed, but all optional features (associated with hardware virtualization) should also be uninstalled.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question by providing CoreInfo64 dump.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132920/discussion-between-ramhound-and-undefinedman).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you may want to try is the BIOS option called "Limit CPUID Maximum" or similar. Microsofts hypervisor has issues with this setting (and doesn't report it). Toggling it disables both WSL2 and Hyper-V on my system, even though all other virtualization works (including WSL1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).